# Python - Return vs Print

Tags: python, printing, return

I have a function to remove punctuation from the end of a word

```
def clean(word):
    if word[-1].isalpha():
        return word.lower()
    else:
        word = word[:-1]
        clean(word)
```

If I run for example, `print(clean('foo!!!'))` the function prints `None`. However if I change `return` to `print` in the function:

```
def clean(word):
    if word[-1].isalpha():
        print(word.lower())
    else:
        word = word[:-1]
        clean(word)
```

Then the function prints `foo`. Why the difference in this case between `return` and `print`?

Comment: Your function isn't truly recursive.  The last line in the first example should be `return clean(word)`.  It will then work as you expect.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga has a better duplicate for this; it's easier to extract the information you need.

Comment: Patrick already gave the most exact explanation... I don't think this is quite an exact duplicate of those...

Comment: The proper question is why the function returns `None`. And that is answered by looking through all of its code paths.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I wouldn't say it isn't *truly* recursive, it just doesn't return anything useful, and doesn't have any useful side-effects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Maybe it would be more accurate to say that it isn't tail-recursion, which is obviously what they were attempting.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call#Description]), *Note that the tail call doesn't have to appear lexically after all other statements in the source code; it is only important that the calling function return immediately after the tail call, returning the tail call's result if any, since the calling function will never get a chance to do anything after the call if the optimization is performed.* I think it may still be tail-recursive, I'm not sure, and I can't tell because Python doesn't optimize tail calls so I can't do a quick experiment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function so it can make recursive call:

```
def clean(word):
if word[-1].isalpha():
    return word.lower()
else:
    word = word[:-1]
    return clean(word)
```